# Sorting txt file to create a leaderboard

Tags: python, sorting, text, numbers

I'm trying to create a txt file each time someone loses in the game (to save their score)

I succeeded and I now have a list of number which I want to sort, biggest first. Then I will use the 5 first lines each time it will be refreshed.

My txt file (for example):

```
10
1
5
4
3
2
```

What I want:

```
10
5
4
3
2
1
```

Thanks

```
#Saving the score    
Scorefile = open('Scoreboard.txt','a')    
Scorefile.write(str(score))    
Scorefile.write('\n')    
Scorefile.close()    

#Sorting the file   
Scorefile = open('Scoreboard.txt','a')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
file = open("Scoreboard.txt","r")
lines = list(file) #create a list of strings
file.close() #don't forget to close our files when we're done. It's good practice.
modified_lines = [] #empty list to put our modified lines in (extracted number, original line)
for line in lines: #iterate over each line
    if line.strip(): #if there's anything there after we strip away whitespace
        score = line.split(' ')[0] #split our text on every space and take the first item
        score = int(score) #convert the string of our score into a number
        modified_lines.append([score, line]) #add our modified line to modified_lines

#sort our list that now has the thing we want to sort based on is first
sorted_modified_lines = sorted(modified_lines, reverse = True) 

#take only the string (not the number we added before) and print it without the trailing newline.
for line in sorted_modified_lines:
    print(line[1].strip())
```

Outputs:

```
10
5
4
3
2
1
```

Comment: Hi , its perfectly working 
But i'm now trying to print these lines on pygame :D , i can't find a way 
Thanks

Comment: @JustinMayer if you can't find a way post another question